# How can I work out using PHP if a domain is .co.uk or .com?

Tags: php

I have two domains with pretty much the same code on both, (version control) but I wanted a little bit of code that would show '(US)' if the viewer was looking at the .com or '(UK)' if the .co.uk, any help welcome...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], -4) == ".com") {
    // you're on the .com domain
}
//... etc
```

Caveat: This relies on the `Host:` HTTP request header, which may not always be sent. (I don't think it's required, if the server is not using name-based virtual hosts.)

A more solid solution would be to make this a configuration variable of the application, which can be automatically changed upon deployment to either of the servers.

Comment: Well, given the client has no idea if the server is using VH or not, I guess it will send it anyway, otherwise the server will not be able to know what to show.

Comment: Stefano: that is still no reason to make assumptions or to rely on it. The developer should still assume that it may not be sent, because it is possible.